# Moving records in SQL

Tags: php, html, sql-server, database

I am looking to move a record from one table to another based on the input of a html form. I know you cant move so I tried the logic of insert then deleting as seen below but it doesnt not seem to be working . Can anyone recommend a change to make here to address this ?

```
<html>
<?php 
$serverName = "x";
$options = array(  "UID" => "x",  "PWD" => "x",  "Database" => "xx");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $options);

if( $conn === false )
     {
 echo "Could not connect.\n";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
 }

  $LicenseGroupID = $_POST['LicenseGroupID'];


$query = "INSERT INTO dbo.[tbl_license_group_delete] 
(License,Group,ID,Vendor_Name,License_Version,Edition,Quantity)
      SELECT *
      FROM dbo.[tbl_license_group]
      WHERE = LicenseGroupID = $LicenseGroupID;

      DELETE FROM dbo.[tbl_license_group]
      WHERE LicenseGroupID = '$LicenseGroupID';

      COMMIT";

  $params1 = 
 array($VendorName,$Version,$Edition,$OperatingSystem,$Quantity);                       
 $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query,$params1);

 sqlsrv_close($conn);
 ?>
 </html>
```

Comment: At least there's extra = here `WHERE = LicenseGroupID` and I would not recommend using `select *` since your code breaks quite easily then. You should also read about sql injection

Comment: The extra where clause has to be there to filter both tables no ? Can change the select *

Comment: Here is a good read on sql injection. http://bobby-tables.com/ Please note, your code is vulnerable.

Comment: I will look at the sql issues once I get the query to work. At the moment i am reading in the value to be moved from a form and move to one table and deleting from another but cant get the query to work

Comment: Did removing the quotes and extra equal sign like I posted below help? Where did things land?

Answer (score 0):

The INSERT says:

```
= $LicenseGroupID
```

and the DELETE says

```
= '$LicenseGroupID'
```

Should the quotes be around the 2nd one?  First thing that comes to mind...

Comment: That's on top of the:

WHERE = LicenseGroupID = $LicenseGroupID;

It should say:

WHERE LicenseGroupID = $LicenseGroupID;

Comment: You should consider using a stored procedure for this as well.  Cleaner... easier to manage ongoing, can test in SSMS before on the front end... all kinds of fun stuff.